# Handle CheckBox Checked Event in Interior Dialog in Basic MSI Project

Tags: events, installshield, installshield-2009, basic-msi

Tools: InstallShield 2009 Premier, Basic MSI Project

I have added an **interior dialog**, and in that dialog I added a **checkbox**.

Now if the checkbox is checked I want to **exit the setup** (or, show a **message box**).

How?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that?  The dialog already has a cancel button, right? I suspect there's a deeper question here and I need to understand the goal to give a better answer.

Otherwise, take a look at behavior and logic | control events and look at how the cancel button does it.  It calls the ControlEvent SpawnDialog argument CancelSetup condtion 1 ( Always ) and the CancelSetup dialog has an EndDialog | Exit event.

Comment: Hello Chrisotopher, there is a text box to enter a license key in the interior dialog, now I have to check whether the text input has matched(with a predefined text), say if not matched I don't want the setup to continue.
How to do it?

Comment: Christopher, how to show a message box from inside an interior dialog (say, if the entered license doesn't match)?

Comment: You want to do this as a controlevent on the next button.  You do something like this:

(Order is top to bottom in IS)

[KEYVALID] {} 1                // SetProperty ControlEvent to always null KEYVALID

[KEYVALID] 1  IS_SERIAL_NUM="MY-LIC-KEY-TXT" // SetProperty CE to set it to one if valid

SpawnDialog BadKey  Not IS_SERIAL_NUM  // spawn modal dialog
NewDialog CustomSetup  IS_SERIAL_NUM   // transition to next dialog

Remember, MSI is an open database so anyone can open it up in ORCA and easily defeat this.